# How to send and save dynamic textbox by group with Jquery Ajax at once?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have dynamic textbox that was already generated. Say two textbox per group. I want to send into web method.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form Name1</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input class="form-control" id="name1" style="width:400px" type="text">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form class1</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input class="form-control" id="class1" style="width:400px" type="text">
  </div>
 </div><br>
 <br>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form Name2</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input class="form-control" id="name2" style="width:400px" type="text">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form class2</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input class="form-control" id="class2" style="width:400px" type="text">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to get value from dynamic count of textbox each two textbox per group with jquery. I want to save per each group (name, class) send with ajax. How the right way to send with AJAX and retrieve data (code behind web method) so that I can looping to save with c#.

The database should save each row :

[image]

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var arr = [];

function gatherInfo() {
  var i = 1;
  for (;; i++) {
    var name = $('#name' + i).val();
    var cls = $('#class' + i).val();
    if (typeof(name) == 'undefined')
      break;
    arr.push({
      name: name,
      cls: cls
    })
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form Name1</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="name1" style="width:400px" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form class1</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="class1" style="width:400px" type="text">
  </div>
</div><br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form Name2</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="name2" style="width:400px" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form class2</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="class2" style="width:400px" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="gatherInfo()">Get Info</button>
```